# Print "total" of entries, outside *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to populate a graph with values that come from an xml file, I can print all the values. The objective is to count all that values and do a simple graph, with one bar that has that total.

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let instance of entityList.list; trackBy:trackerByFn; let idx=index;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of entityList.metadata.graphContent"  [ngSwitch]="column.order">
           <td *ngSwitchCase="'1'">{{getValue(instance, column.key) | ellipsis:200}}</td>
      </ng-container>
   <i>   ---  {{idx+1}}</i>
</tr>
```

with that code I print all "codes" that represent each document:

```
2010/010 --- 1
2010/003 --- 2
2014/025 --- 3
2014/019 --- 4
2014/021 --- 5
2014/020 --- 6
2010/011 --- 7
2010/001 --- 8
```

I just want to print: 8, outsite the *ngFor's, to use on my html graphs.
PS: getValue returns this.objectPath.get(object, key);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print `entityList.list.length` outside *ngFor to show number of values.